# How do have multiple provider in changenotifierprovider?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I have encountered the following problem where I have no idea how to add another `changenotifierprovider` to my `app.dart`. Before that I already have the `EntryProvider()`, Now I wish to add another provider called `EnterProvider()`. Below is my coding for `app.dart`:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => EntryProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          home: WelcomeBackPage(),
          theme: ThemeData(
            accentColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            primaryColor: Colors.black,
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.openSansTextTheme(),
          ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,),
    );
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Use [MultiProvider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#multiprovider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **MultiProvider** .

```
 MultiProvider(
  providers: [
   Provider<Something>(create: (_) => Something()),
   Provider<SomethingElse>(create: (_) => SomethingElse()),
   Provider<AnotherThing>(create: (_) => AnotherThing()),
  ],
  child: someWidget,
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to work it out.